# multi-client program without multi-threading

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

Is there any way to write a multi-client program using sockets in Java without multi-threading?

I heard about socket mapping but how does it work?

I know multi-threading, but for now I should not use it.

Comment: like simply having two sockets in one class? or what? This for the server? or the client?

Comment: You can make a single threaded server with non-blocking IO.  However I wouldn't.  Multi-threading -- and multiple CPUs -- is the only way of scaling a single box.  Modern systems rely too much on multi-threading.  Removing it would not be best practice.

Comment: @3kings Clients need to communicate with each other...

Comment: @markspace What do you mean?(single threaded)How is it possible for more than one client

Comment: @faraa See Walter's example below.  That's what I mean.  Notice he set the selector to non-blocking mode (`server.configureBlocking(false)`).

Comment: Also, if you want to learn more, I'll recommend O'Reilly's "Learning Java." http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023463.do  It covers Java IO, NIO and non-blocking selectors in more detail.  A good book to own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I just threw this together. This is just an example to programming with **java.nio**. I think this code is fairly straight forward. It binds a ServerSocket to ports 3000-3009. Whenever a client sends data it will echo it back to them. Itcan handle as many connections as possible. You should implement more error handling of course but it will be harder to read then for reference. Handling data in this way is a bit more difficult than using thread per client approach, if you want it's possible to have a hybrid type server where inactive connections go into non blocking mode and when you start receiving data you can jump back into blocking mode with a cached thread pool.

To test it out just open a shell and use **telnet localhost 3000**

```
  Selector selector = Selector.open();
  for(int port=3000;port<3010;port++){
     ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
     server.configureBlocking(false);
     server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
     server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
     System.out.println("Bound to " + server);
  }

  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(0x4000);
  while(selector.isOpen()){
     selector.select();
     Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
     while(keys.hasNext()){
        SelectionKey key = keys.next();
        if(!key.isValid()) continue;

        if(key.isReadable()){
           buffer.clear();
           SocketChannel socket = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
           if(socket.read(buffer) == -1){ //-1 is end of stream
              System.out.println("Client Disconnected " + socket);
              socket.close();
              continue;
           }else{
              buffer.flip();
              socket.write(buffer); //echo data back to client
           }

        }else if(key.isAcceptable()){
           ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel)key.channel();
           SocketChannel socket = serverChannel.accept();
           socket.configureBlocking(false);
           socket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
           System.out.println("Client Connected " + socket);
        }
     }
     selector.selectedKeys().clear();
  }
```

Comment: thank's...so there isn't any way to use traditional IO to solve this problem...yes?

Comment: If you mean java.io package then no. Those are all blocking sockets. If you want to check out a library I have no experience with but gets alot of praise you can check out http://netty.io/